# Ktable does not work with two same messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have made the sample program convert the stream to Ktable. when I output the stream it always give me same number of result if I produce same message with same key any number of time

Input

- key1- value1
- key1-value1
- key2-value2

Actual output

- key1- value1
- key1-value1
- key2-value2

Expected output

- key1-value1
- key2-value2

```
    @Bean
    public java.util.function.Function<KStream<String, WorkInstructionEvent1>, KStream<String, WorkInstructionEvent1>> inputStream() {
                return stream ->
                        stream.toTable(Materialized.<String, WorkInstructionEvent1, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("new-table")
                                .withValueSerde(CustomeSerdes.WorkInstructionEvent1Serdes()).withKeySerde(Serdes.String())).toStream();
            }
```

here is the spring propeties file

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputStream-in-0.destination=inputStream-in-0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputStream-out-0.destination=inputStream-out-0
```

If I send the same message two times in the `inputStream-in-0` it will output the same message two times in the `inputStream-out-0`

Comment: I need clarification on what the issue is. Can you please edit the question so we know what the expected behavior is vs. what you see?

Comment: I have updated the text you can see now input and actual output and expected output .

Comment: There's a similar issue for KTable-KTable joins: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6599 .... could you tell me what happens when you disable caching on the state store?